# Decorator factory on a unittest method

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-decorators

```
def register_processor2(processor_name='SomeProcessor'):
    def decorator(func):
        class SomeProcessor(GenericPaymentProcessor, TriggeredProcessorMixin):
            name = processor_name
            transaction_class = Transaction

            @staticmethod
            def setup(data=None):
                pass

        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            PaymentProcessorManager.register(SomeProcessor)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            PaymentProcessorManager.unregister(SomeProcessor)
            return result

        return func_wrapper
    return decorator


def register_processor(func):
    class SomeProcessor(GenericPaymentProcessor, TriggeredProcessorMixin):
         name = 'SomeProcessor'
         transaction_class = Transaction

         @staticmethod
         def setup(data=None):
             pass

    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        PaymentProcessorManager.register(SomeProcessor)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        PaymentProcessorManager.unregister(SomeProcessor)
        return result

    return func_wrapper


class TestPaymentMethodEndpoints(APITestCase):
    @register_processor
    def test_put_detail_cannot_change_processor(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

Ok so the decorator `register_processor` works as expected. And the test fails, but I want to make the name of the inner class customizable so I went for a decorator factory implementation instead.

The thing is when running the test decorated with `register_processor2` I get the following:

`AttributeError: 'TestPaymentMethodEndpoints' object has no attribute '__name__'`

This is from `@wraps(func)`, my question is why is `func` here an instance of `TestPaymentMethodEndpoints`, and not the bound method?

Also if I remove the `@wraps` decorator then the **test runs and passes**.
I'd expect that the test would not be discovered as `func_wrapper` does not start with `test_*` and even if it is discovered then it should fail.

Any insight on what is happening and how I'd go about doing this?

**EDIT**

So I figured it out even if the decorator factory has arguments that have default values you still need to place `()` when calling it.

But would still love to hear an explanation of what happened in case of the tests passing / getting discovered in the first place.

```
class TestPaymentMethodEndpoints(APITestCase):
    @register_processor()
    def test_put_detail_cannot_change_processor(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

Makes sense now that I think about it :D, gosh you learn something new each day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're now asking "how come the `unittest` module can find test cases that have been wrapped in functions with names that don't start `test`?"

The answer to that is because `unittest` doesn't use the *names* of the functions to find the methods to run, it uses the *attribute names* of the test case classes to find them.

So try running the following code:

```
from unittest import TestCase

def apply_fixture(func):

    def wrap_with_fixture(self):
        print('setting up fixture...')
        try:
            func(self)
        finally:
            print('tearing down fixture')

    return wrap_with_fixture


class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @apply_fixture
    def test_something(self):
        print('run test')


print('Attributes of MyTestCase: %s' % dir(MyTestCase))
print('test_something method: %s' % MyTestCase.test_something)

mtc = MyTestCase()
mtc.test_something()
```

You will see that the output from `dir` contains the name `test_something`:

```
Attributes of MyTestCase: ['__call__', ...lots of things..., 'test_something']
```

but that the value of that attribute is the wrapping function `wrap_with_fixture`:

```
test_something method: <function apply_fixture.<locals>.wrap_with_fixture at 0x10d90aea0>
```

This makes sense when you consider that when you create a function you are both creating a function with the name provided and a local variable with the same name, and that the decorator `@` syntax is just syntactic sugar, so the following would have been an equally valid albeit longer-winded way of creating your test case class:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        print('run test')
    # Overwrite existing 'local' (or 'class' variable in this context) 
    # with a new value. We haven't deleted the test_something function
    # which still exists but now is owned by the function we've created.
    test_something = apply_fixture(test_something)
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense but why did the test pass in the first place :D. I mean it shouldn't.

Comment: Is it possible you were getting confused about when and when not to put the brackets after the decorator factory? You might have created a test case that was actually just a decorator function, e.g. `def decorator_factory(*args, **kwargs): ... return decorator`, then `@decorator_factory  def test_method(self): self.assertEqual(True, False)`, so here the decorator factory is called with `test_method` and returns a decorator that is used as the test case, but that just creates a new function wrapping the test and doesn't actually run the test, so would appear to pass.

Comment: Either that or when running the test it catches assertion errors and stores the failed tests in a dict of some sort based on the test function __name__ which would not be in the dict so it ignores it. Anyway I got the gist of it in essence, thank you.